# How to get friends id on Facebook API 3.15

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm new with the Facebook Sdk and I'm try to develop an app that get my friends ids from Facebook, but on the new SDK Facebook API (3.15), it is no longer possible to access to my friends list, unless they accept the permission for that, and my friends need to be using the current app.

So, I have two accounts on Facebook and two different devices, and i just want to find myself on the app.

I turn on the "status & reviews" and added my email on "Facebook developer", and I know how to connect to my own account, but how to get the id from the second account?

Here is my code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {


    Request request;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




                // start Facebook Login
                Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

                  // callback when session changes state
                  @Override
                  public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                    if (session.isOpened()) {
                            session.getDeclinedPermissions();



                      // make request to the /me API
                      Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                        // callback after Graph API response with user object
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                          if (user != null) {
                            TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                            welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!" + "\nYour id: "+user.getId());

                          }
                        }
                      }).executeAsync();
                    }
                  }
                });
              }

              @Override
              public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                  Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
              }




}
```

Any one?!

Comment: /me/friends will only return friends that are also using the app. There is nothing you can do to get all friends

Comment: I know that. I mentioned it in my question. My question is how to find friends that users